# Adding a trendlineType other than "linear" to openpyxl trendline results in error

Tags: python, charts, openpyxl

Adding a trendline to openpyxl line charts works only if no trendlineType other than "linear" is selected, e.g "poly", "exp" or "power".
This works:

```
series = Series(data, title=sheetname)
            series.trendline = Trendline(
                dispEq=True, dispRSqr=True, trendlineType="linear")
            c1.append(series)
```

This does not and the charts fails to be build:

```
            series = Series(data, title=sheetname)
            series.trendline = Trendline(
                dispEq=True, dispRSqr=True, trendlineType="poly")
            c1.append(series)
```

Even though, the docs claim that this should work: [Doc Link](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/openpyxl.chart.series.Trendline.trendlineType)

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Edit:
Python is not failing but opening the excel file results in:
[image: Excel detects error]
[image: Error]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><logFileName>error094400_01.xml</logFileName><summary>Errors were detected in file '...'</summary><removedParts><removedPart>Removed Part: /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml part.  (Drawing shape)</removedPart></removedParts></recoveryLog>
```

Comment: Please [edit] to include the full error traceback in the text of your question

Comment: @G.Anderson I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found an [issue](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/761) where it is said that additional data has to be supplied.

For poly, `series.trendline.order = 2` this is needed e.g.